# Basic encryption program

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

```
encryption_library = {'A':'!','B':'@','C':'#','D':'$','E':'%','F':'^','G':'&','H':'*','I':'(',
                      'J':')','K':'-','L':'_','M':'+','N':'=','O':'`','P':'~','Q':'{','R':'[',
                      'S':'}','T':']','U':':','V':';','W':'"','X':'<','Y':'>','Z':'0','a':'1',
                      'b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'a',
                      'k':'b','l':'c','m':'d','n':'e','o':'f','p':'g','q':'h','r':'i','s':'j',
                      't':'k','u':'l','v':'m','w':'n','x':'o','y':'p','z':'q'}

orig_file = open('Plain_Text_File.txt','r')
file_read = orig_file.read()    
orig_file.close()
encrypt_file = open('ENCRYPTED_Plain_Text_File.txt','w')

for ch in file_read:
    if ch in encryption_library:
        encrypt_file.write(encryption_library[ch])
    else:
        encrypt_file.write(ch)

encrypt_file.close()
encrypt_file = open('Plain_Text_File.txt','r')
file_read = encrypt_file.read()
encrypt_file.close()
codes_items = encryption_library.items()

for ch in file_read:
    if not ch in encryption_library.values() or ch == '.' or ch == ',' or ch == '!':
        print(ch)
    else:
        for k,v in codes_items:
            if ch == v and ch != '.':
                print(k,end='')
```

Can someone walk me through this basic encryption program step-by-step? Specifically, what happens after the first "encrypt_file.close()"?

Comment: Is your question about `dict.items()`, the for loop over a string? Or printing some items in some if statements?

Comment: so, a plain text file is opened in read mode, and is then read (and closed). then, an empty encrypt file is opened in write mode and all the values associated with the keys in the plain text file (in the encryption dictionary) are written to it. however, i don't really understand why the plain text file has to be read again. I know you can't just skip this part (that would make those lines of code redundant), but i can't seem to figure out what goes on next...

Comment: Where is this code even coming from? This is extremely unsafe encryption and unpythonic code

Comment: i'm trying to work through some optional questions in my textbook, and this was one solution to a problem. there is actually a decryption segment to the problem as well, but i'm assuming once i understand this section, i'll understand the decryption as well.

Comment: The program does essentially the same thing twice. In the first block, it writes the "encrypted" text to a file and in the second block (after the first `encrypt_file.close()` it just prints the "encrypted" text out; with a newline at the end, if the char is not in the `encryption_library` or a dot

Comment: You should not try to learn by this example, though. This is extremely bad code